# How to get flow to typecheck props given to it from a HOC?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, recompose

For example:

```
import { withProps } from 'recompose'

type Props = {
  name: string,
};

const NameTag = ({ name }: Props) => (
  <p style={{color: 'pink'}}>
    { name }
  </p>
);

const MyNameTag = withProps({
  // i want a error here
  name: 1
})(NameTag);
```

How can I get an error that I cannot pass the number `1` to the prop `name` for the NameTag component?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least Flow 0.78 will give you an error as soon as you use the HOC.

So if you add a `<MyNameTag />` on your code, it should give you this.

```
string [1] is incompatible with number [2] in property name of the first argument.

 [1]  7│   name: string,
      8│ };
      9│
     10│ const NameTag = ({ name }: Props) => (
     11│   <p style={{color: 'pink'}}>
     12│     { name }
     13│   </p>
       :
 [2] 19│   name: 1
```

This probably happens because you can still pass `name` when instancing `NameTag` and up until that point it's not clear that it will fail.

Flow is so complex and my flow-fu is weak so I would not dare to say this is a flow bug.

So far, the only way I have found to catch errors on declarations is to build a HOC that only allows the properties that were not overridden and nothing else. You will need to declare components with strict properties `{| a: string |}`. Check this example:

```
// @flow

import * as React from 'react'


function myWithProps<
    MP, // My Properties. These are the pre-entered properties.
    CP, // Component properties. The properties originally expected by
        // the component.
    C: React.ComponentType<CP>, // The original component itself. Used to
                                // extract the properties template CP.
    IP: $Diff<CP, MP>, // Input properties. Properties that must be received
                       // by the HOC. We only expect the properties of the
                       // original component CP minus the properties MP that
                       // were specified when we created the HOC.
    >(myProps: MP): C => React.ComponentType<IP> {
        return component => props => <component {...myProps} {...props} />;
}


type Props = {|
  name: string,
  age: number,
|};


const NameTag = ({ name, age }: Props) => (
  <p style={{color: 'pink'}}>
    { name } { age }
  </p>
);


// $ExpectError. name has a wrong type.
const MyNameTag = myWithProps({name: 1})(NameTag);

// Should work.
const MyOtherNameTag = myWithProps({name: "hello"})(NameTag);

// Should work.
<MyOtherNameTag age={21} />;

// $ExpectError. name cannot be overriden.
<MyOtherNameTag age={21} name={"John"} />;

// $ExpectError. age has a wrong type.
<MyOtherNameTag age={"21"} />;

// $ExpectError. age missing.
<MyOtherNameTag />;

// $ExpectError. Unexpected parameter.
<MyOtherNameTag age={21} nmae={"John"} />;
```

myWithProps uses generic types so it should work with any class.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I am using the library 'recompose' so I would like to avoid making my own HOC's as much as possible. I am also using Flow v0.75 so I will try updating.